# Mongo, How to do a join after a find?

Tags: mongodb, join

I have collection like such:

```
purchases = [
    {_id: 0, user_id: 3, product_ids: [ObjectId_1, ObjectId_2... etc]},
    {_id: 1, user_id: 4, product_ids: [ObjectId_3, ObjectId_2... etc]}
]
```

I have an index on user_id. Basically I'd like to get all the purchases by a user with the data of the products. Something like:

```
purchases = [
    {_id: 0, user_id: 5, products: [{name: 'hammer'}, {name: 'drill'}... etc]},
    {_id: 1, user_id: 5, products: [{name: 'bat'}, {name: 'ball'}... etc]}
]
```

How do I do that?

I am looking at `$lookup` but it seems like the `$lookup` seems to be on the entire table. I don't want that since after finding the furst list of purchases, finding the product ids is a small subset of the entire table...

It also seems inefficient to do `find()` on the purchases collection, followed by mapping each result with `find` on the product ids, since some product_ids will duplicate.

What is the proper way to do this join in mongo?

Comment: `$lookup` does a left outer join on equality condition and pulls all the matching document from the other collection. I'm not sure why you think it is on the entire table.

Comment: @Veeram the command is `db.collection.aggregate`. Doesn't that imply it is on the entire collection? In my example I have 2 entries in the purchase collection that match a user id, so the join should only pull in a handful of product ids. If I run `db.purchases.aggregate` doesn't that imply I will be doing a left outer join on the entire purchases collection?

Comment: You'll need a `$match` before you do `$lookup` to filter the purchases. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `$match` before `$lookup`.

```
db.purchases.aggregate({
    $match: {
        "user_id": 5
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$product_ids"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "products",
        localField: "product_ids",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "products"
    }
})
```

Comment: ty did not see that.